# How to write long arithmetic expressions in several lines in python?

Tags: python, newline, code-readability

I have a long expression, its' not fitting in my screen, I want to write in several lines.

```
new_matrix[row][element] =  old_matrix[top_i][top_j]+old_matrix[index_i][element]+old_matrix[row][index_j]+old_matrix[row][index_j]
```

Python gives me 'indent' error if I just break line. 
Is there way to 'fit' long expression in screen?

Comment: i think \ will work..

Comment: See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) advice. If you put the expression in `()` then you can break on the operators, e.g. `+`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I hate backslashes, so I prefer to enclose the right hand side in parens, and break/indent on the top-level operators:

```
new_matrix[row][element] = (old_matrix[top_i][top_j]
                            + old_matrix[index_i][element]
                            + old_matrix[row][index_j]
                            + old_matrix[row][index_j])
```

Comment: this seems the most legit.. i hate slash lines

Answer (score 4):

You can break expressions into multiple lines by ending each line with `\` to indicate the expression will continue on the next line.

Example:

```
new_matrix[row][element] =  old_matrix[top_i][top_j]+ \
    old_matrix[index_i][element]+old_matrix[row][index_j]+ \
    old_matrix[row][index_j]
```

Comment: It's not good to continue a line with the same indentation as the start segment.

Comment: Fair point, edited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `\`:

```
new_matrix[row][element] =  old_matrix[top_i][top_j]+old_matrix[index_i]\ 
                            [element]+old_matrix[row][index_j]+old_matrix[row][index_j]
```